# Generic Parameter Type and Return Type in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a Java method which accept a Object type and the type of data type it should be converted to.

For example if I should be able to return a value of 1 as Int or Double as required. I am using Class to pass the data type as parameter.

**Question:**
How can I make the method generic to accept return type based on the input parameter?

The below code is just an example and it may be syntactically incorrect and provided to explain my question.

```
public class JavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getValue(1,int.class);
        getValue(1,double.class);
        getValue("adf",String.class);
    }

    public static <E> void getValue(Object obj,Class<?> type) {
        if (type == String.class) { 
            // return string value
        }else if (type == int.class) { 
            //return Integer.parseInt(obj);
        }else if (type == double.class) { 
            //return Double.parseDouble(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `?` with `E`?

Comment: I tried it but I could not make the return statement work.

Comment: Why are you even trying to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can I make the method generic to accept return type based on the input parameter?

The type parameter can be used to designate the method's return type, and you can associate that with the `Class` argument by means of that argument's type parameter:

```
public static <E> E getValue(Object obj, Class<E> type) {
```

You will also need to use `Class.cast()` to satisfy the compiler that the method returns the correct type.  (You could also use an ordinary cast, but that will be subject to type safety warnings.)  For example:

```
    // ...
    } else if (type == Integer.class) { 
        return type.cast(Integer.valueOf(obj.toString()));
    }
```

Note also that you cannot this way effect conversions directly to primitive types, as your code suggests you are trying to do.  You must instead convert to their wrapper classes.  In other words, you cannot use `int.class`, `double.class`, *etc*.; you must instead use `Integer.class`, `Double.class`, and so forth.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
       int i=  (int) getValue(10,int.class);
       System.out.println("int value -->"+i);
      Double d = (Double) getValue(25.023,double.class);
      System.out.println("double d-->"+d);

        String s=(String) getValue("adf",String.class);
        System.out.println("String s-->"+s);
    }

    public static   <T> Object getValue(Object obj,Class<?> type) {
       return obj;

    }
```

Comment: Why would you need if statements if you are returning the same object?

Comment: We dont need if statements, since your post has that if condition i pasted from it.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
       int i=  (int) getValue(10,int.class);
       System.out.println("int value -->"+i);
      Double d = (Double) getValue(25.023,double.class);
      System.out.println("double d-->"+d);
      
        String s=(String) getValue("adf",String.class);
        System.out.println("String s-->"+s);
    }

    public static   <T> Object getValue(Object obj,Class<?> type) {
                  return obj;
    
    }

Answer (score -2):

Since java methods can only return one result, you have to do a bit of work around. As you surely know, you can return an `Object`.

As mentioned here: [Return different type of data from a method in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140964/return-different-type-of-data-from-a-method-in-java)
you can write your one class with two private values of different types to ask later which of them is set!

So applying this to your question you could write something like this:

```
public class ReturningValues {
public final double y;
public final int x;

public ReturningValues(double y, int x) {
    this.y = y;
    this.x = x;
}
}
```

And then use this class as the return-value of your method:

```
public static ReturnValues myMethod(){
    ReturningValues rv = new ReturningValues(null,1);
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: You're fond of NPEs, are you?  You can't pass `null` to a parameter of primitive type.