# How to Type Cast a String as Null object?

Tags: java, if-statement, casting, conditional-statements

UPDATE: Apologies for the confusion. All code MUST be written between the forward slashes i.e. the "//" beginning at the TO DO comment. And ends the line before the return answer.

Consequently this:

return price<20 ? "Buying new shirt" : null

is unfeasible as return answer is OUTSIDE the allowed code modification area.
I also didn't know if it was possible to assign a null object to a String object (as my comment indicated. And yes, I'm aware of the difference between "null" v null. That is the entire issue I'm having with the code failing to compile.

The ConditionalStatements() method is supposed to pass an integer input and return a string variable called answer.

If the passed integer `price < 20` (to include negative integers), then the return variable `answer = "Buying new shirt"`. Otherwise the compiler's expected return value for answer must be `null` i.e. the OBJECT null and NOT the string "null" which answer is initialized with.

Constraints:

- if statement MUST be a Simple Conditional Statement with no branching.
- cannot use catch try or other statements. Limited to use of compound conditionals and variables.
- **MUST be WITHIN the area designated by // forward slashes.**
  Because of this last constraint, I can't see a way to typecast/return the null as the test errors are indicating. Apologies again for the confusion.

---

I've tried short circuiting using && and the || operators. Tried getting creative with && and II operators in the if statement to make compound statements. e.g:

`if ( (answer.equals(null) && (price >=20) )` etc.

to trap the incorrect test input and change answer data type.  But compiler fails test cases of required `answer = null` for cases where `price >= 20`. Returning answer = "null" throws an error as a String object is returned v. the desired null.

How to type cast answer variable e.g. (null) answer = null; in my code below?

```
public class ConditionalStatements {
 /**
 * This method is used for problem one in the README.
 * @param price A price that will be passed in by the test.
 * @return String A string used to validate the test.
 */
public String simpleConditional(int price) {
    String answer = "null";
    **// TODO: Write Step 1 code between the forward slashes** <--start code modification area
    (answer == null ) || (price < 20)  )
    answer = "Buying new shirt";
            
      if( (price >= 20)  )  {                
           answer = null; //this assignment is legal according to post feedback. 
                          //However it STILL results in test failure message (shown in URLs below). 
                         //Where the compiler is expecting a null object and not a string object.... 
                          //compiler won't accept answer = null; How to typecast answer String variable so it will accept null object?
      }       
    // **<---this is the END of the code modification area**

    return answer;
}
```

When compiler tries to compile, it fails with these test run errors:

All tests. Only price < 20 passed:
https://i.postimg.cc/TYrH051P/allTests.png

Test 3: price = 20, expected return for answer = null
https://i.postimg.cc/W3GJCVk0/Test3-err1.png

Test 4: price = 21, expected return for answer = null
https://i.postimg.cc/bNJsHk3x/Test4-err2.png

Comment: `"null"` != `null`

Comment: *illegally trying to assign null object to String object.* Why do you think it is illegal?

Comment: What do you mean with "illegally trying to assign null object to String object"? Is that an actual error message, that you get from somewhere, or your own interpretation? Because that line is perfectly valid Java code, and i don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: `if( (price > 20)  ) return null;` or simpler `return price<20 ? "Buying new shirt" : null`

Comment: Here is a workaround: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140964/return-different-type-of-data-from-a-method-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140964/return-different-type-of-data-from-a-method-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do assign `null` to answer variable, rather than "null" string. Check the below code, I think it does what you want to achieve.

```
public class ConditionalStatements {
 /**
 * This method is used for problem one in the README.
 * @param price A price that will be passed in by the test.
 * @return String A string used to validate the test.
 */
public String simpleConditional(int price) {
    String answer = null;
    // TODO: Write Step 1 code between the forward slashes (answer == null ) || (price < 20)  )
    if(price < 20){
    answer = "Buying new shirt";
    }

    return answer;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    ConditionalStatements var = new ConditionalStatements();
    System.out.println(var.simpleConditional(10)); // prints "Buying new shirt"
     System.out.println(var.simpleConditional(25)); // return null object
}

}
```

Comment: `if(answer == null` doesnt make any sence here, because it is always true

Comment: Totally Agree, got carried away with the comment put by OP.

Answer (score -1):

To use `null` with explicit type you have to put a cast in front of `null`, in you example

```
  if( (price >= 20)  )  {                
       answer = (String) null; 
  }
```

Comment: `null` has no type

Comment: That is true. But to make it use as it has a type you could add a cast in front of `null`. E.g, you have to use this to test  overloaded methods if you call the method with `null` directly.

Comment: The cast is not necessarry. The return value can not be overridden.

Comment: Not the return type but the argument.

Comment: There is no argument `answer` in the code

Comment: That was only an example where you put a cast in front of  `null`. And yes: ` null` itself is not an object anyway.